# Report Builder Expressions

Tags: expression, reportbuilder

Im new to Report Builder and having issues with some expressions that Im trying to implement in a report.  I got the standard ones to work however as soon as I try any distinctions, I get error messages.  Over the last couple weeks, Ive tried many combinations, read the expression help, google and looking at other questions at internet sites.  To reduce my frustrations, I even would jump to other expressions and walk away hoping I would have different insight coming back. 
 Its probably something simple or something I dont know about writing expressions. 
 Im hoping that someone can help with these expressions; they are the versions I get the least errors with(usually just expression expected) and show what Im trying to accomplish.

```
=IIF((Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value)='D',COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!TICKETNUM.Value),0)
=IIF((Fields!TRANSTYPE.Value)='1' and (Fields!RECORDFLAG.VALUE)='A' or 
  'B',SUM(Fields!DOLLARS.Value),0)
=IIF((Fields!TRANSTYPE.Value)='1' and 
  (Fields!RECORDFLAG.VALUE)='P',SUM(Fields!DOLLARS.Value),0)
=Sum([DOLLARS] case when [RECORDFLAG]='P' then -1*[DOLLARS])
```

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post the error messages? One thing to note though is that SSRS uses "THINGY" (double quotes) and not 'THINGY' (single quotes). That might help.

Comment: Okay, it might be slower reaction on my part; my computer& desk is public & im not the only user, so I try to keep things tidied up, therefore past notes arent available, if i didnt keep them with printouts; So, I figured the beginning is best start

Comment: Can you post your updated expression?

Comment: =IIF((Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value)='D',COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!TICKETNUM.Value),0)  The Value expression for the textrun ‘RECORDFLAG2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected.

Comment: =IIF((Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value)=”D”,COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!TICKETNUM.Value),0)
The report runs and just puts a 0 in the field; For the parameter date requested, the value should have been 1; This seems like the better statement, however Im still missing something.

Comment: =IIF((Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value)=”D”,COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!TICKETNUM.Value))  The Value expression for the textrun’RECORDFLAG2. Paragraph[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter ‘FalsePart’ of ‘Public Function IIF(Expresion as Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object’.

Comment: =IIF((Fields!TRANSTYPE.Value)="1" and (Fields!RECORDFLAG.VALUE)="A" or "B",SUM(Fields!DOLLARS.Value),0)
The report runs and the field value is: #Error. The only change from original expression is the double quotes you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> =IIF((Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value)=”D”,COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!TICK‌​ETNUM.Value))

The error message gives you the answer here - no false part of the `iif()` has been specified.  Use `=IIF((Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value)=”D”,COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!TICK‌​ETNUM.Value), 0)`

> =IIF((Fields!TRANSTYPE.Value)="1" and (Fields!RECORDFLAG.VALUE)="A" or "B",SUM(Fields!DOLLARS.Value),0)

This is not how an OR works in SSRS. Use:
`=IIF((Fields!TRANSTYPE.Value)="1" and (Fields!RECORDFLAG.VALUE="A" or Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value = "B"),SUM(Fields!DOLLARS.Value),0)`

The 0s are returned due to your report design. `countdistinct()` is an aggregate function - it's meant to be used on a set of data. However, your `iif()` is only testing on a per row basis - you're basically saying "if the current row is thing, count all the distinct values" which doesn't make sense. There are a couple of ways forward:

- You can count the number of times a certain value occurs in a given condition using a `sum()`. This is not the same as the `countdistinct()`, but if you use `=sum(iif(Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value = "D", 1, 0))` then you will get the number of times RECORDFLAG is D in that set. Note: this requires the data to be aggregated (so in SSRS, grouped in a tablix).
- You can use custom code to count distinct values in a set. See https://itsalocke.com/aggregate-on-a-lookup-in-ssrs/. You can apply this even if you have only one dataset - just reference the same one twice.
- You can change the way your report works. You can group on Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value and filter the group to where Fields!RECORDFLAG.Value = "D". Then in your textbox, use `=countdistinct(Fields!TICKETNUM.Value)` to get the distinct values for TICKETNUM when RECORDFLAG is D.

Comment: Thank you for info.  I saw your post today but traffic was prominent and I didn't have a free moment to concentrate on computer.  I'll try the answer on Tuesday and let you know if it's successful. Take Care.

Comment: I believe you are correct; The 0s are returned due to the report design.  Ill probably need to use custom code to count distinct values and I appreciate the link.  I may work further on this and read more to work with the code, just cause its over my head.  My decade old knowledge of Access & GIS and reading the help section to learn Report Builder can only carry me so far. At least Im pointed in the right direction.  And the custom code should be able to help me calculate daily values, which is my goal. Thanks for all your help.